# Notification remain on home screen

Tags: android-emulator, android-versions, android-sdk

I am using GFive Presdent Tango 7. Its showing notifications Like "Viber is denied to read sms" and "android.google.setting denied to read location".These notification appear on screen one by one .. and not disappear.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have enabled App Permissions in Security Settings of your phone.

So for making it dissappear.Just go to Settings>Security and disable App Permissions.

And one more those notifications where shown because your have denied accessing specific permission requested by the app before sometimes.

This is a security feature.If you want to enable it and still wanna get rid of it.Jz goto App permissions and select specific application for which you want to grant access specific permission.

Hope it answered the question.